# How to automatically handle low disk space?

Tags: mysql, disk-usage

Currently one of our prototypes has a very bad caching system.
In a matter of minutes it fills up it's harddrive and makes the system unusable.
What I need to do then is to restart mysql service to free up the space.

My question: Is there a way to restart the mysql-service when the disk gets above 95% usage?

I know this is quite unorthodox. And yes, I'm aware that this is not really a solution, but we're talking about a prototype that has to run for a presentation and other tests purposes rather than be stable and proper.

Answer (score 1):

If you use `systemd` to start `mysql` then you can add `LimitFSIZE` to the unit file.

Without `systemd` you can use `ulimit`:

```
bash -c 'ulimit -f 100; dd if=/dev/zero of=bigfile bs=10M count=1; echo foo'
```

Both approaches do not refer to the free space, though. You have to calculate in advance how much they may consume.

Maybe file system quota are more flexible (I am not familiar with those). That would be an option if you have a user account which just runs `mysql` (which is probably the case anyway).

Answer (score 1):

As you say, you are asking for an unorthodox solution, but since you acknowledge that, you can check free space with `df`

```
df /partition/you/need/to/monitor
```

Parse the output of that, and based on what you find, restart your mysql service. You'll probably need root privs for that, so you might need to give yourself permission to restart the service with a [passwordless sudo](https://serverfault.com/questions/160581/how-to-setup-passwordless-sudo-on-linux) setting.

You can automate all of that with cron.

Answer (score 1):

If you use monit you might be able to do this to monitor the filesystem and restart mysql-services when disk space is too low.

Check https://mmonit.com/monit/documentation/monit.html#filesystem_flags_testing